# Meaning of "Around In"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Can somebody explain what does the author mean by using two prepositions after travel?

> With the construction of new subway and bus lines,
>   Beijing became a much more comfortable place to travel **around in**.

Can I leave the last "**in**" part of the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasal verb "travel around" to make journeys in a particular region. The word "in" is not quite redundant. Compare

> I travelled around in Beijing
>
> I travelled around Beijing

The second seems to describe a tourist, who is in Beijing to travel. The first suggests the situation of someone who has to travel because they are there for some other reason such as work, or living in Beijing.

Answer (score 1):

> When criticized for occasionally ending a sentence on a preposition, Winston Churchill replied, "This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put." Churchill's reply satirizes the strict adherence to this rule.  ([Source](https://www.irmi.com/articles/expert-commentary/never-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition-and-six-other-myths-about-writing))

It is common, especially when using spoken English, to end a sentence with a preposition.  I remember being taught in High School (age 16-18) that one should not do that, but it happens all the time.

Therefore, yes, you can (and should) leave the final "in" in the sentence.

**Around in**

This particular idiom has at least two meanings.  The first is the meaning expressed in your sentence: the ability to move throughout (inside) the city.  The second meaning is "to arrive in an estimated or approximate amount of time."

> I'll come around in an hour.

Or, more commonly for my area...

> I'll come 'round in about an hour.

Comment: The example could also be phrased, "In an hour I'll come around." The thing I will do is to _come around,_ and the time when I will do it is _in an hour,_ that is, one hour from now. The time may be approximate, but the word "around" has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @DavidK you are correct.  "Around" used idiomatically means travel/visit/arrive etc.  it refers to the fact that you're moving, not how long it takes you to move.